# Context menu in Android DialogPreference... is it possible?

Tags: android, contextmenu, dialog-preference

I'm trying to create a context menu in a `DialogPreference` for an Android app (targeting API level 8, in case it's relevant).  I've managed to get the menu to show (when an item in a `ListView` is clicked) via a slight hack, but I have no idea how to handle any resulting command.  What I have so far is:

- In my `onItemClick` handler, I do the following:

  ```
  list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener (new ContextMenuGenerator(control, position));
  list.showContextMenuForChild (control);
  list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener (null);
  ```
- `ContextMenuGenerator` does the following:

  ```
  public class ContextMenuGenerator implements OnCreateContextMenuListener
  {
      // additional code redacted - not necessary for this question

      @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
      {
           new MenuInflater(context).inflate (R.menu.address_set_preference_popup, menu); 
      }
  }
  ```

This results in the correct menu being displayed at the right time, but I have no idea what happens after I select an item.  I presume `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem)` is called on the `Dialog` that the `DialogPreference` creates, but I have no idea how to get from there to code that I can handle that event in -- I don't see any way of subclassing that `Dialog`, nor does there appear to be a way of attaching an external listener to either it or the `ContextMenu`.  Is there some other way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be no way to attach a listener to the Dialog or to the `ContextMenu` itself, but it turns out that the individual `MenuItem`s that the `ContextMenu` contains *do* support a listener interface.  The answer, therefore, is to modify `ContextMenuGenerator` thus:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        new MenuInflater(context).inflate (R.menu.address_set_preference_popup, menu);
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size (); i ++)
            menu.getItem (i).setOnMenuItemClickListener (listener);
    }
```

where `listener` is an `OnMenuItemClickListener` that I passed in to the constructor and stored in a field.